# Change Store view then should be change curenccy Magento?

Tags: magento

When change store view in Magento frontend. then currency should be change for each store view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will paraphrase the answer of St0iK. You can't set different base currency per store, but you can do it per website. First you have to go to the admin panel -> System -> Configuration -> CATALOG -> Catalog -> Price -> Catalog Price Scope and change it from Global to Website. Now when you go to the admin panel -> System -> Configuration -> GENERAL -> Currency Setup -> Currency Options you can change Base Currency per Website, not only for Default (Global). So you have to transfer you stores to websites and you will be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

you have to go for `System > configuration > Under current configuration scope > select stores` and according to that under  `General > currency set up` , chnage currency